# Set cell value based on other cell's function result by google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to set "status" is 'UP' when the result of column "CountID" change from 0 to >= 1 by google script

- I have 2 sheets, **main** sheet have table below, **raw data** sheet have raw data auto refresh every hour.
- Column "CountID" from main sheet count id from raw data sheet using arrayfomula and CountA function. *=arrayformula(COUNTIF('raw data'!A2:A11,A2:A))*
- In my official spreadsheet, the column index may change therefore, I must use the column header ("Status", "Count") to refer to column position.
- "Status" column from main sheet using data validation dropdown list with up to 6 value like: (Cancel, Pending, UP, DOWN, Return ...)
- Testing sheet: [Testing sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-1WZecQv56ZZ5qIhV21Oh_Kqmr9i18eWsyh1HFFh64/edit?usp=sharing)

| ID | Status | CountID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | UP | 1 |
| a2 | pending | 0 |
| a3 | UP | 2 |
| a4 | UP | 5 |
| a5 | Cancel | 0 |
| a6 | pending | 0 |

The code below working and I just upgrade for column header reference to ensure script working when column index change.

Thanks
Jacques-Guzel Heron.

```html
function updateStatus() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var status_col = headers.indexOf('Status');
  var countid_col = headers.indexOf('CountID');

  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("main")
    .getDataRange();
  var statusRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("main")
    .getRange(1,status_col+1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var newData = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][countid_col] > 0) {
      data[i][status_col] = "UP";
    }
    newData.push(new Array(data[i][status_col]));
    Logger.log(countid_col);
  }
  statusRange.setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a fast Apps Script project easily to update the `Status` column of your Sheet by using [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). I will show you how in the example below. I chose to run the trigger every half an hour with the [`everyMinutes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) method, but you can adapt it to your needs. First you would have to run the `createTrigger` function once to create the trigger. Then the function `updateStatus` will run automatically every half hour. Please check the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class to learn more about the applied methods.

```js
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateStatus').timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();
}

function updateStatus() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("main")
    .getDataRange();
  var statusRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("main")
    .getRange("B:B");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var newData = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][2] > 0) {
      data[i][1] = "UP";
    }
    newData.push(new Array(data[i][1]));
  }
  statusRange.setValues(newData);
}
```

Please keep in mind that the code above only checks if the `CountID` column equals to `1` or greater to set up the `UP` status. Therefore, if the `CountID` gets lowered to `0` the status will still be `UP`. Please drop a comment if you need further advice with this approach.

Comment: Thank your your replying! I wonder can we get column header (status, countID) to refer to column instead of column index. Cuz in my offcial sheet I have alot of column and their index can change. do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: You can check this post for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346918/get-column-values-by-column-name-not-column-index